# Any reason to use !0 instead of true?

Tags: javascript

I found some code using

```
!0
!1
```

I guess this is just the same things than

```
true
false
```

is there a reason for doing that or is just some abbreviation?

Comment: Find who wrote that code and make a note not to hire him or her for any future work. :-)

Comment: I would guess it's mainly for obfuscation/uglification.

Comment: @Pointy This code is produced by [JavaScript Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home), as an example. Is it a time to fire it? ;)

Comment: @VisioN Ha ha!  Well then that makes perfect sense I guess.

Comment: In JS it make sense, it can save some loading time. But its definetely ugly :-)

Comment: It turns out we had some compiled/compressed code, we needed to modify it to solve a bug, so someone copy/pasted and !0/!1 was left there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you really care about bandwidth and loading time then you need code compression. `!0` and `!1` is a compressed version of `true` and `false`.

Comment: This should be done after with a build script like [Uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS). If you write this in your source, it will end up unreadable!

Comment: Isn't `1` shorter then `!0`?

Comment: @freakish `typeof 1 === 'number'` and `typeof !0 === 'boolean'`

Comment: @freakish by adding a leading ! operator, it will grantee the return value is a bool rather than a Number. another example is !undefined will return you a true

Comment: Yeah, but why do we care about the type?

Comment: Show me the piece of code (real code), where replacing `!0` with `1` won't work.

Comment: @JeffShaver That's not a real code, noone uses such constructs.

Comment: @freakish absolute equal operator (===) is a suggested one when you comparing variables of types you are sure. this is recommended by book JavaScript the Good Parts

Comment: @freakish its the point. 1 is only true when using loose comparison (`==`). basically, the point everyone seems to be making is that if you really, really need to save bandwidth, 2 characters is less than 4 or 5. That is really the only reason they would use `!0` and `!1`

Comment: I'm talking about `if (x===true)`, obviously a good programmer will use `if(x)`.

Comment: @freakish not if you want to test if `x` is a boolean AND is `true`. In that case you would have to test `if (x === true)`. If you use `if (x)`, x could be the number 1 or 2 or 3 and it will run (or any other positive number)

Comment: @JeffShaver Of course. I understand it. But that sounds highly unlikely that someone will actually use such type check. At least I've never seen it in real code.

Comment: @Emissary ? Whatever you want to tell me I'm pretty sure that comments is not the best place for that.

Comment: @JeffShaver `x` could be even any not `falsy` value which would evaluate to true for **everything except** `0` `null` `false` `""` `NaN` and `undefined`

Comment: @freakish I have an example, let's think this scenario: I want pass my JS object to server as JSON and let server C# library such as Json.net to parse it as an object. so if my JS object is {name:'abc', checked: true}, the it will be serialized as "{"name":"abc","checked":true}" this could be easily parsed by Json.net; on the other hand if you have JS object as {name:'abc', checked: 1} then you the JSON string will be "{"name":"abc","checked":1}", so Json.net will parse checked as integer.

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 true. I was just giving a short example.

Comment: @freakish And the point being, you should type check? It doesn't make sense not to in "real" code.

Comment: @JeffShaver It doesn't make sense to use weakly typed language and to do type checking, to be honest.

Comment: @freakish It wouldn't make sense for a code minifier to change the actual meaning of the code

Comment: @freakish then fight all of us over the answer? I don't really know what you want at this point.

Comment: @JeffShaver I'm not fighting at all. I'm not saying that the answer is wrong. Since when discussing is fighting?

Comment: @Shuping Are you telling me that value `1` is hardcoded? Well, I suppose that it may happen in a really rare scenario. I stand corrected.

Comment: @all Mind continuing this discussion in the [Javascript Channel](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) ?